# Similar colors for similar data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Suppose that I have data like this:

```
Time, variable, value
0, A, 1.2
1, A, 2.3
2, A, 3.4
0, B, 1.1
1, B, 2.4
2, B, 3.7
0, C, 1.2
1, C, 2.1
2, C, 3.3
0, D, 1.4
1, D, 2.5
2, D, 3.5
0, E, 1.8
1, E, 2.9
2, E, 3.1
0, F, 0.8
1, F, 2.2
2, F, 3.3
0, G, 1.7
1, G, 4.3
2, G, 4.4
0, H, 1.0
1, H, 2.2
2, H, 3.1
```

If I do something like `qplot(Time, value, color = variable, data = mydata, geom = "line")` I will get in this case 8 different-colored lines by default. Suppose that the data A,B,C,D are related and the data E,F,G,H are related. I want to show this relationship by color. How can I tell R that I want A,B,C,D to be, for example, plotted as similar but distinguishable shades of blue, and D,E,F,G to be plotted as similar but distinguishable shades of green?

Comment: There's no function for "similar but distinguishable" colors in ggplot. You might try attaching some property to alpha to maybe change the color slightly or mapping the line type? But you're probably going to just have to specify the colors manually with `scale_color_manual` to get the results you want.

Comment: And how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4):

You can make custom scales by first grouping your dataset and then specifying the color brewer for your two groups. The `brewer.pal` function allows you to pick from scales of common colors.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(groups = factor(as.numeric(df$variable %in%
                                          LETTERS[1:4])))

blues <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, "Blues")[3:6]
reds <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, "Reds")[3:6]

    ggplot() + 
      geom_line(data = df, 
                aes(x = value, y = variable, 
                    group = variable, 
                    color = interaction(factor(groups),
                                        variable))) + 
      scale_color_manual("Variable", labels = unique(df$variable),
                         values = c(blues, reds))
```

[image]

Comment: Oops I didn't see this before I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. I actually had 10 time series, and I wanted to group them visually by color in two sets of five:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
# you have to pick the last 5 of 9 colors because if you just specify 5 colors, the first will be way too pale 
blues = brewer.pal(9,"Blues")[5:9] 
greens = brewer.pal(9, "Greens")[5:9] 
mycolors = append(blues, greens)
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x=Time, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_line() + theme_classic() + scale_colour_manual(values=mycolors)
```

Not perfect--the order of the colors you create matters, you have to create the same number of colors as you have data series--but it's better than finding and typing in RGB values IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is just add a new variable and categorize A, B C, D in one group while E, F, G, H in the other.

```
    mydata$variable=as.character(mydata$variable)
    mydata$variable1=mydata$variable
    ifelse(mydata$variable1[]==c('A','B','C'),'a','b')
```

Hope it helps!